# Differentiability of squared distance function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization

In one of my classes, my professor made this comment-

> "Distance function is not always differentiable. However, it is always differentiable if the set is closed and convex, where, the distance function of a point *x* from a set *X* is defined as-
> $$ \text{Dist}(x,X)= ||x-  \Pi_X(x)|| $$
> $\Pi_X(x)$ being the projection of the point *x* onto the set *X*."

Is there any proof of this? Also, I am a little bit confused about this statement. For example, how come the squared distance function in terms of 1-norm is always differentiable since it contains absolute value terms? Even more confusing, if I plot 1-norm squared in Geogebra- $$ z = (|x|+|y|)^2 $$
the surface indeed looks smooth.

I understand that 2-norm is not always differentiable, but 2-norm squared is always differentiable. But I am not sure about the 1-norm case. Also, I am wondering how to prove the statement.